# Is there any way to connect MSSQL server to .NET CORE (2.2) API without using EF?

Tags: c#, .net, api, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am a new to.Net Core, As of now, I am trying to connect an existing database in MSSQL Server from.Net Core API.

But all the examples I have found around is using EF.

But I want to connect the MSSQL server from the user-defined class as follows.

DataBaseConnection.cs

```
 public class DatabaseConnection 
    {
        private SqlDataAdapter sqlAdapter;
        private SqlConnection sqlConnection;
        SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand();

        // Initialise Connection

        public DatabaseConnection()
        {
            sqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);
        }

        // Open Database Connection if Closed or Broken

        private SqlConnection openConnection()
        {
            if (sqlConnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed || sqlConnection.State == ConnectionState.Broken)
            {
                sqlConnection.Open();
            }
            return sqlConnection;
        }
}
```

Inside the constructor, I got the error as

[image]

appsettings.json

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=HealthAPI;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Is there any possibility to do the connection with the database without using EF ?

Comment: Yes. The error you are getting is about Configuration Manager. It's not a database connection error. If you hard coded your connection string in there it'd probably work.

Answer (score 1):

I did that using workaround. Below is the code.

```
public abstract class BaseDataService
{
    private Database database = null;

    public BaseDataService()
    {
        DatabaseFactory.SetDatabaseProviderFactory(new DatabaseProviderFactory(new SystemConfigurationSource(false).GetSection), false);
        this.database = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("_connection");
    }
    public Database SqlDatabase
    {
        get
        {
            return this.database;
        }

        set
        {
            this.database = value;
        }
    }
}
```

App.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="system.data" type="System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactoriesConfigurationHandler, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
  </configSections>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="_connection" connectionString="Server=localhost;Database=DBNAME;Trusted_Connection=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"  />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Usage

```
public class MyDataService : BaseDataService
{
    public IList<Test> ReadTest()
    {
        IList<Test> testList = new List<Test>();
        DbCommand selectCommand = null;

        selectCommand = SqlDatabase.GetStoredProcCommand("[dbo].[CSP_Test_SelectAll]");

        using (DataSet result = SqlDatabase.ExecuteDataSet(selectCommand))
        {
            if (result.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                DataTable dataTable = result.Tables[0];
                feesList = dataTable.ConvertTo<Test>();
            }
        }

        return testList;
    }
}
```

Packages needed

```
<PackageReference Include="EnterpriseLibrary.Data.NetCore" Version="6.0.1313" />
```

Edit:

I went through your code and issue is getting config values

```
public DatabaseConnection(IConfiguration configuration)
{
      string connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
      sqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
      sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this

```
Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings").DefaultConnection
```